# RegEx for having minimum 3 chars also first and last char should be single quote

Tags: javascript, regex

Team

I would like to have a RegEx (in javascript) to validate below conditions.

1. Value should have atleast 3 chars
2. First and last char should be single quote.

please advice how the regex should be?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](/tour) (you get a badge!) and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: This question shows no research effort at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean three chars total:
`const regex = /'.+'/;`

If you mean three chars plus quotes:
`const regex = /'.{3,}'/;`

More info:
https://javascript.info/regexp-quantifiers